# Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated in migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I'm trying to **migrate** but I get this error:

```
Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated
```

I don't know why this happens to me. I think problem is not from foreach because I'm following a tutorial and the OnModelCreating Part is the same.

this is my context:

```
 public class DataBaseContext : DbContext, IDataBaseContext
{
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<CatalogBrand> CatalogBrands { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CatalogType> CatalogTypes { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var item in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (item.ClrType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditableAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            {
                builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime>("InsertTime");
                builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime?>("UpdateTime");
                builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime?>("RemoveTime");
                builder.Entity<User>().Property<bool>("IsRemoved");
            }
        }

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogBrandEntityTypeConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new CatalogTypeEntityTypeConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }

   
}
```

I also have an override for SaveChanges() in my context but I think it does not relate to problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!
I should've just changed the following:

```
 builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime>("InsertTime");
 builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime?>("UpdateTime");
 builder.Entity<User>().Property<DateTime?>("RemoveTime");
 builder.Entity<User>().Property<bool>("IsRemoved");
```

To following:

```
builder.Entity(item.Name).Property<DateTime>("InsertTime");
builder.Entity(item.Name).Property<DateTime?>("UpdateTime");
builder.Entity(item.Name).Property<DateTime?>("RemoveTime");
builder.Entity(item.Name).Property<bool>("IsRemoved");
```